# For constructors, is {} the same as =default?

Tags: c++, c++11

In a default constructor's definition, is `= default;` exactly the same as `{ }`? Are there any situations where they might have different meanings?

Sample pseudocode:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct S // maybe with base classes
{
    S() = default;    
    // S() {}    - same or different?

    // other stuff...
};
```

Comment: This actually depends on where the `= default;` occurs.

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, if you have any non-static data members then those members are default-initialized instead of value-initialized where value-initialization can occur.

Comment: @user2864740 good job. I tried SO search with pretty much exactly that and nothing came up :|

Comment: Note that all the discussion in the dup and the answer below assume that the defaulting occurs on the first declaration. AFAIK there is no difference between `struct S { S(); }; S::S() = default;` and `struct S { S(); }; S::S(){ }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are different. By `S() {}`, `S` is considered to have a user-provided constructor, while `S() = default;` not. This makes a difference, for example, as to whether `S` qualifies as an aggregate type. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: Another point is that trivial constructibility requirements cannot be met with a user-provided default constructor.